# show one div and hide the rest onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

https://leiacarts.github.io/index.html

https://codepen.io/leiacarts/pen/PoqRxNZ

I'm trying to get images to show in the red portions and to stay within the content div, but any time I add images, the layout breaks. I would really appreciate some help with these two things I want to achieve and thank you in advance:

1.) keep images constrained to and auto resizable within the (red) content div

2.) hide the images when the section is "shut" onclick.

HTML:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="bookmark">&#8593; ten &#8596; sion &#8595;</div>
  <div class="content"><p></p>
    <!-- <div class="space"></div> -->
      <!-- <img class="fit" src="images/ziptiesmall.png">
      <img class="fit" src="images/ziptiesmall2.png">
      <img class="fit" src="images/ziptiesmall3.png"> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

the JavaScript:

```
var sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section")

sections.forEach(function(section) {
  section.addEventListener("click", expandSection);
})

function expandSection(event) {

let section = (event.target.classList.contains("section")) ? event.target : event.target.parentNode;


sections.forEach(function(section) {
  section.classList.remove("open")
})

section.classList.add("open");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added this class to the rest of the divs which didnt have any images on them, hence the reason for them to show the red content div. Remove the 100%, the image text in between every column as well and create ids for every column and add background image to them and you are good to go :).

```
.content.bg.zip {
    margin-left: 40px;
    /* width: 100%; */
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url(images/ziptiepattern.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Comment: I have multiple different images that I want to include in the red sections, not just one, and they need to be scrollable. Would background let me do that?

Comment: Nope you have to fall back to html this time and use img tags.

Comment: I've updated to show what it looks like when I do that (the red is gone now). When I click on the section, things work like I want for the most part, but on load and when I click out, the images aren't hidden along with the section. How do I hide the images until the section is clicked?

Comment: The github page, though I've updated codepen now too. (The images are broken on codepen but it's the same concept)